How to update to latest version of ggplot in Google colab with R kernel?
It appears that within the past week (I write this on 4/20/2024), the default ggplot2 package version pre-installed with the R kernel in Google colab is 3.3.5, a very old version.  I have lots of code for a forecasting class using the forecast package that, when run a week ago, loaded ggplot2 version 3.4.4 and worked fine.  This code no longer works with 3.3.5.  I have tried to update to the latest version of ggplot2, but am running into problems with the rlang package: the latest versions of ggplot2 depend on rlang >= 1.1.0, whereas the default is rlang 1.0.1.  Trying to update the rlang package seems to violate the R kernel itself!
Here is my notebook where I try to update ggplot to latest version and follow a rabbit trail that depends on the IRkernel package behind the whole notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/171EZU5Qyar-a768EUxlm1pyVXbh9TE1v?usp=sharing
Two questions,

why is the "new" default ggplot2 package so old;
how can I update it??

I can update rlang and hence ggplot2 on my local machine by wiping the namespace, but I can't do this in a Colab notebook which reconnects every time and loads old versions of namespaces!

Update: on 4/22/24, Colab seems to have reverted back to newer versions of rlang (1.1.3) and ggplot2 (3.4.4).  Not sure why there was a temporary reversion back to older versions of these packages.
